# How to trigger validation when user removes original field value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am well aware of JQuery validation's lazy behavior. In reality, it is only semi-lazy in that if a field contains a valid value, loses focus, and then is changed to an invalid value, an error message is displayed immediately, even before the field is unfocused again. This behavior is very reliable, except in one very specific scenario that I want to find a workaround for.

If a field initially contains a valid value, changing it to a non-empty invalid value triggers immediate validation, as expected. But *removing* the initial value does not trigger validation. Example:

```
<form id="muh-form" action="post">
  <input name="input1" type="number" value="10" required min="10"/>
  <br/>
  <input name="input2" type="text"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

If the user changes "10" to "1" and unfocuses the field, an error message appears immediately, as expected. Furthermore, if the user then changes "1" to empty, the `required` validation is triggered, as expected.  Only a direct transition from initially valid to empty fails to trigger validation.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r60L5bfx)

As a workaround, can I force the validator to immediately validate all fields when the form is loaded?

Comment: @SajibKhan Not so. If you input a non-empty value (valid or not) that differs from the initial value, then clear the field, the required validator is triggered as expected.

Comment: You are describing "lazy" validation, which is the default behavior of this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quote OP:  If the user changes `input1` to some value < 10 and unfocuses the field, validation is triggered as expected. But if the user simply removes the initial value (without first changing it) and unfocuses the field, validation is not triggered.

You are describing the default validation of the plugin, which is called "lazy" validation.  [See the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo):

> *"**Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy:** Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value"*

If you'd like to use "eager" validation instead, then you'll need to use a custom `onfocusout` callback function...

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    // "eager" validation
    this.element(element);  
}
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/r60L5bfx/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/r60L5bfx/3/)**

Comment: My first sentence describes lazy validation, but my second sentence describes a deviation from the normal behavior.  The documentation does not accurately describe the plugin's behavior. If a field contains a valid value which is then changed to an invalid value, you *will* see error messages as you tab through the form, for *all* cases except the complete removal of an initially valid value.

Comment: @TKK, yes, the documentation is lacking in some areas.  However, I'm showing you exactly how to manipulate the behavior you're complaining about.  In my demo, you *will* see error messages when you tab through the form for ALL case *including* the complete removal of an initially valid value.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.valid()` in `change` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#muh-form").on('change', function(e) {
    $("#muh-form").valid();
  });

  $("#muh-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) { }
  });
});
```

[**JSFiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/sajibcse68/r60L5bfx/2/)